# xinput does not list my touchpad

Tags: arch-linux, drivers, touchpad, xinput

My touchpad does not work at all in Arch Linux, and other distributions. `xinput` does not list it. Physical mouse works fine.

I recently bought a Packard Bell EasyNote ENTG71BM with Windows 8.1 installed. I purged it and installed Linux Mint, with which the touchpad *did* work (albeit with issues, like lacking two-finger scroll). I later installed Arch instead, and now the touchpad does not work at all. I have also tried Kubuntu and Fedora from Live USBs, and in neither of the cases does the touchpad work.

**How can I make Arch at least recognize the touchpad as a mouse?** I have installed xf86-input-synaptics (and a few similar packages) via pacman, but when going to touchpad settings from GUI, I get a red message "synaptics driver not installed (or is not used).". Also, running `synclient` gives "Couldn't find synaptics properties. No synaptics drivers loaded?".

I will post any requested additional info.

Am currently planning on trying some more live USBs to see if any will work. Most notably if mint will work again...

**Edit:** Nothing worked, but when I got the random idea to to into BIOS and boot using UEFI instead of Legacy, the live USB I had tried just before could use the touchpad without problems.

I'll accept any answer that can comment on why this fixed that issue.